# Dog may have eaten staples

Tags: dogs, health

My dog may have eaten 3 or 4 staples, while playing. Is there any danger for its health? I think it will emit them, but in case it doesn't what are the possible effects in its mood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible side-effects in mood?

That's going to be dependent on each animal, but it can be anything from no effect to slightly more irritable to feeling a little less energetic.

You're right on the money, you just want to watch your dog and take him to the vet if there's anything that concerns you. You *can* take him to the vet now, if you want to.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest being cautious here, and consulting a vet.

There's a few things that would worry me here. Staples tend to have sharp tips, and break off into smaller wires that could get stuck. They might also cause internal damage as a result. I'd rather play it safe cause of this.

A vet might also be able to advice you to what to look out for, in terms of stool movement, or general disposition, and know about things like bloating. Ours, thankfully is a seriously picky eater, but we've had a good vet who's adviced us pretty well since we started going to them.